knapsack problem - how to cut memory usage
You have  items. Each object has a weight, the weight of the object numbered  is equal to _. You need to put them in a backpack that holds no more than g. At the same time, you want the TOTAL WEIGHT of ALL items in the backpack to be as large as possible and at the same time it (the total weight) to be ODD. If you cannot put an odd weight, you will enter 0.
Input data
The first line gives the number of available items 0≤≤25. The second line lists  numbers—the weights of the objects. The weights of the items do not exceed 10^9. The third line contains the number 0≤≤10^18, a limit on the total weight of the items that will be placed in the backpack.
Output
On the first line print the largest odd total weight of objects that can be put in a backpack.
**MY SOLUTION **
import sys

def max_odd_weight(n, weights, S):
    possible_sums = {0}  
  
    for weight in weights:
        current_sums = set(possible_sums)  
        for w in current_sums:
            new_sum = w + weight
            if new_sum <= S:
                possible_sums.add(new_sum)  

    max_odd_weight = 0
    for w in possible_sums:
        if w % 2 != 0 and w > max_odd_weight:
            max_odd_weight = w

    return max_odd_weight

n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
weights = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))
S = int(sys.stdin.readline())

result = max_odd_weight(n, weights, S)
sys.stdout.write(str(result))

It's really fast BUT I have a problem passing tests (All correct but memory limit exceeded). Test data is hidden.
How can I cut the usage of memory even more?
time limit for test - 3 seconds
Memory limit per test -  256 megabytes
input - standard input
output - standard output
using SYS helped, but not much

Can you add sample input and output? And a link to the website?

Sure
Examples
Input
3
1 4 8
10
Output
9
Input
4
5 7 12 18
20
Output
19
Input
5
3 5 3 3 5
10
Output
9
Input
5
72 74 42 68 57
100
Output
99
Unfortunately, the site is my university's contest and is private, so I cannot provide any links

That's all examples that are visible btw
Other tests are hidden
My code passes 42 tests, no problems except memory usage
42 passed with 608 ms 262100 Kb

possible_sums should be the set, and current_sums should be the list.

current_sums = tuple(possible_sums)
is a bit faster, but speed is not a problem

yes, also tried
possible_sums should be the set, and current_sums should be the list.
but still overusage of memory

Do you have a link to the problem?

Oh, nevermind, I misread.  posslbe_sums is already a set.  The confusion I think is because you wrote 1018 instead of 10^18 and 109 instead of 10^9

No, I cannot provide any links, cause its a private contest in my unicersity, sorry

Is 109 actually 10 to the power of 9?

Sorry for miscommunication, will fix the numbers

Yes its acrually 10^18 and 10^9

Are you sure you should be asking about an ongoing contest though?

Yes, the speed is good, but the problem is overusage of memory

That's not a competition actually, but a some kind of a lab

I mean no winners or anything, but task should be done

Modified with this:
weights = [weight for weight in weights if weight <= S]
if S in weights and S % 2 != 0:
sys.stdout.write(str(S))
sys.exit()
will help sometimes, but still not passed the test

The constraints on the problem mean that there could be over 34 million possible sums, which won't fit in memory if you use the standard dynamic programming solution for 0-1 knapsack.
There are a limited number of items, though, so I suggest recursive backtracking instead, like this:
import sys

def max_weight(weights, start, limit, odd):
    result = None if odd else 0
    for i in range(start, len(weights)):
        w = weights[i]
        if w <= limit:
            testodd = not odd if (w%2)==1 else odd
            test = max_weight(weights, i+1, limit-w, testodd)
            if test != None:
                test += w
                if (result == None or test > result):
                    result = test
    return result

n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
weights = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))
S = int(sys.stdin.readline())

result = max_weight(weights, 0, S, True)
sys.stdout.write(str(result))


It's working good only in
Input
5
3 5 3 3 5
10
Output
9
But with
result = max_weight(weights, 0, S, False) it fine with any other open test results  ( Input 3 1 4 8 10 Output 9 Input 4 5 7 12 18 20 Output 19  Input 5 72 74 42 68 57 100 Output 99) except  Input 5  3 5 3 3 5 10 Output 9

Oh, yes, I made a mistake in propagating the oddness check. Fixed.

btw can you explain how to count if the solution will fit into memory/time limits?

Well, this solution uses very little memory.  Yours takes memory for each possible sum.  There can be 34M possible sums, so the 256 MB limit leaves you less than 10 bytes for each one.  They can be pretty big numbers and you put each one into 2 sets or so -- much bigger than 10 bytes each.

You could simplify this by just choosing to include or exclude the element at the current index.

I could, but recursion is slow in python

Separate the up to 25 numbers into two parts with up to 12 and 13 numbers. Compute and sort all possible sums for each part. Combine them with a saddleback search, i.e., go through one set of numbers ascendingly and the other descendingly so that the sum of the two sums stays just under S. For that annoying oddness thing, actually combine the even sums from one set with the odd sums from the other, both ways.
